# Github https pages are not working in Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, markdown, microsoft-edge, github-pages, cloudflare

I am using the github pages as web pages, I enforced https to make is secure and also configured my DNS on Cloudflare. My webpages are working fine on google chrome but not working on Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer. 
Here is the screenshot with error.

http://prntscr.com/oqez7m

It gives the below error.

*SEC7120: [CORS] The origin 'ms-appx-web://microsoft.microsoftedge' failed to allow a cross-origin font resource at 'ms-appx-web:///assets/Fonts/BrowserMDL.ttf#Browser MDL2 Assets'.*

CSS3119: No fonts available for @font-face rule

I have tried to enabled/disabled TLS/SSL settings on Cloudflare, even I disabled Always use HTTPS.

Here are the settings on Github. 
http://prntscr.com/oqf2sf

Github pages with HTTPS should work on all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by setting the appropriate TLS version on Azure webapp and Cloudflare. On Cloudflare, it should be same or lower version.

On Azure set TLS version under TLS/SSL settings

[image]

On Cloudflare TLS Version settings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a CORS related issue. For testing purpose, try to modify some settings may help to fix the issue for IE and Edge browser.

(1) Make sure that security level for all the zones are similar in internet options.

(2) Try to go to path below.

> Internet options -> Security tab -> Custom level -> Allow data sources
>   across domains

Enable that option.

[image]

Again try to make a test to see whether issue get fixed or not.

Comment: Did you try to check for that error for @font-face rule? Do you have any this kind of rule in your code? If yes, Did you try to remove it for testing purpose to see whether it solve the issue or not? You can try to check why it said fonts are not available. it may help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: The issue was resolved on my end. As per my understanding that the issue is related to the TLS version difference. I was using TLS 1.3 which is not compatible with Azure webApp.